# express mongoose Mongodb not inserting properly

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following schemas. When I try to register a new `user`, mongodb replaces the last registered user's name with the new one's. ObjectId stays the same for that entry. Have no idea why it's doing that. No errors.

I `console.log`ed everywhere in the post api and everything is fine. The entry is seen in the database but has replaced the latter. Could the issue be my schema design? Something tells me it's the way I'm making everything `String` in the schema definitions. I'm building with MEAN.

```
var AnswerSchema = Schema({
    response    : { type: String, default:null},
    question    : { type: String, ref: 'Question'},
    employee    : { type: String, ref: 'User'}
})

var QuestionSchema = Schema({
    title : String,
});

var UserSchema = Schema({
    username : String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Answer', AnswerSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**api**

```
var Question = require('../models/questions'); 
var User = require('../models/users'); 
var Answer = require('../models/answers');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = "markov";
var user = new User(); 
var question = new Question();
var answer = new Answer();

// Export routes to the main server.js file
module.exports = function(router) {
    /* ====================
    User Registration Route
    ==================== */
    router.post('/users', function(req, res) {
        user.username = req.body.username;

        if (req.body.username == null) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Ensure username is provided' });
        } else {
            // If criteria is met, save user to database
            user.save(function(err) {
                console.log(user.username);
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Username already exists!' });
                } else {
                    res.json({ success: true, message: 'user created!' }); // If all criteria met, save user
                } 
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `user.username` looks very suspect. Where is the instance being created? It's certainly not in the scope of the `.post()` here. Somewhere you are calling `var user = new User()` and that instance is sticking around. So the same information stays there just like you are describing. Show the code including where you actually make that call. But really you should simply be calling `new User()` within this scope.

Comment: I've added the code. i call `var user = new User()` at the top.

Comment: So don't do that. Call `new User()` "within" the `.post()` and any other request methods in the same module. This is not like "imports". You are declaring a variable, and scope matters. So you want a "new" one with every request. Then you won't have the problem.

Comment: Also. Please use the `{ }` symbol in the editor when adding code to your posts, or simply press `Ctrl + K` to indent as code. The Other `< >` symbol on the editor is for "snippets", which are blocks of contained HTML, JavaScript CSS like plnkr and co, used to run interactive examples. Your Node.js code does not belong in snippets. Edited them out several times now.

Comment: yes my bad. works now. I'm new to this mongoose thing. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is the right way to create and save new users. You create new user by instantiating User model and passing an object to it as parameters. To see what I mean, refer to my solution below.

```js
var Question = require('../models/questions'); 
var User = require('../models/users'); 
var Answer = require('../models/answers');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = "markov";
// you don't define new User model here!
// var user = new User(); 
var question = new Question();
var answer = new Answer();

// Export routes to the main server.js file
module.exports = function(router) {
    /* ====================
    User Registration Route
    ==================== */
    router.post('/users', function(req, res) {

        if (req.body.username == null) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Ensure username is provided' });
        } else {
            // If criteria is met, save user to database
            // create new user 
            var newUser = new User({ username: req.body.username });
            newUser.save(function(err) {
                console.log(user.username);
                if (err) {
                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Username already exists!' });
                } else {
                    res.json({ success: true, message: 'user created!' }); // If all criteria met, save user
                } 
            });
        }
    });
```